# Dismissing trailing white space at the end of a String when using a regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

The problem I’m facing here is that the current regex I created does not fully work. If there is no white space at the end of my String it fails. My question is there any way to resolve this?

Here are the details of the question:

I need a regex that ensures Strings conform to the following format,

```
“LL=xxxxxx LL=xxxxxxxxx LL=xxxxxxx”
```

L = Letter.
X = Letter or number or punctuation mark.

The closest regex I have is,

```
([\\pL]{2}=[\\pL|\\pN|\\pP]+ )+
```

But this regex does not work and will only work if the String is in the Format:

```
“LL=xxxxxx LL=xxxxxxxxx LL=xxxxxxx ”
```

Here is code I use to check:

```
    final String regex1 = "([\\pL]{2}=[\\pL|\\pN|\\pP]+ )+"; 
    String x = "xx=xxxxxx xx=xxxxxxxxxm xx=xxxxxxx xx=xxxxxxx"; // This is what I need!
    String y = "xx=xxxxxx xx=xxxxxxxxxm xx=xxxxxxx xx=xxxxxxx "; // This works, no good
    System.out.println(x.matches(regex1));
    System.out.println(y.matches(regex1));
```

Comment: Note that a `|` inside a character class does not mean "OR" will match a literal `'|'` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the space with `(?: |\z)` and it should work.

```
([\\pL]{2}=[\\pL\\pN\\pP]+(?: |\\z))+
```

The `(?: |\z)` is a non-capturing group that matches a space or end of input.

Note that in `[\\pL|\\pN|\\pP]`, the `|` does not mean "or".  You probably want `[\\pL\\pN\\pP]` which means any one of any letter, number, or punctuation character.

Comment: You’ve actually screwed this up due to the doubled doubled backslasheses.  You should post regexes without the dumb string doubling so that they can be read and printed out and compared. You meant to say `([\pL]{2}=[\pL\pN\pP]+(?: |\z))+`. However, for many reasons that is not a very good pattern all in all. Why brackets around `\pL`? Those are superfluous. Plus I cannot see any use in quantifying a capture group instead of simple cluster group. You probably want something more like `(?x) ^ (?: \b \pL{2} = [\pL\pN\pP]+ \p{Zs}* )+ $` instead, with the `(?x)` added for legibility & elbow-room.

Comment: @tchrist, I meant to say what I said.  I made the minimal changes to the input regexp necessary, so the OPer can copy-paste it into their code.

Comment: Then you failed: your pattern is broken because the st∞pid Java preprocessor turned your `\z` into `z`. But there is no reason to mimic a dumb and largely broken regex to begin with. Don’t put brackets around things that don’t need it, and rethink how you are doing the end, because **what you have does not work.**

Comment: @tchrist, The Java preprocessor, whatever that is, doesn't turn `\z` into `z`.  That's a compile-time error.

Comment: Downvote removed.  The JPP is what I call the thing that turns \uXXXX escapes into code units.

Comment: Umm, maybe you have your own "Java preprocessor", but there is no such thing as part of an Oracle Java distribution. Perhaps you're thinking of the C preprocessor, but that doesn't process string escapes, it does macro expansion.

Comment: Ah I understand.  `javac` takes in files of bytes, converts them into files of UTF-16 code-units, decodes escape only `\uxxxx` sequences in those, then lexes, then converts the lexemes into a parse tree, which feeds that into the actual compiler.  I've heard the bytes->UTF-16->decoded UTF-16 part of the pipeline as the "pre-lex" passes.